# What is the kernel of $R[T] \to R[w]$, $w=u/v$, $vt-u \in R[T]$ prime.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be an integral domain, not necessarily integrally closed.
Let $0 \neq v,u \in R$.
Assume that $vT-u$ is a prime element of $R[T]$
(then, by Exercise 4 page 102 in Kaplansky's book "Commutative rings",
$-u,v$ is an $R$-sequence).

What is the kernel of $R[T] \to R[w]$, where $w=u/v$?
(I do not mind to further assume that $R$ is Noetherian).

Some remarks:

(1) [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319353/what-is-the-kernel-of-rt-to-rw-t-mapsto-w-w-u-v-u-v-in-r-wher?noredirect=1&lq=1) is similar: Instead of "$vT-u$ is prime" it assumes "$R$ is integrally closed".

(2) On the one hand, perhaps, in view of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319223/what-is-the-kernel-of-kx2-x3t-to-kx-defined-by-t-mapsto-x), there is no hope to prove that an element of the kernel has the form $bT-a$, with $a/b=u/v$.

(3) On the other hand, in remark (2), the minimal polynomial $x^2T-x^3$
is not prime ($x^3,x^2$ is not a $k[x^2,x^3]$-sequence),
so maybe there is still some hope to have a nice answer to my current question.

(4) I wonder if the theory of anti-integral elements is relevant here.

Comment: It looks like the ideal you are looking for might be a contraction of an ideal. 
The containment $R \subset R[w]$ induces $R[T] \subset R[w][T]$, and the morphism $R[T] \to R[w]$ is the composition of $R[T] \subset R[w][T]$ and $R[w][T] -> R[w][T]/(w-T)$. So, $(w-T)R[w,t] \cap R$ is the ideal you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure yet I completely understood the last line in your argument. (I will let you know later if I still have problems understanding it. You can post your comment as an answer, if you wish).

Comment: I think [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/798783/121097) could be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much! The answers to that question are indeed helpful!

Comment: The hint in Exercise 3 page 102 in Kaplansky's book "Commutative rings", is that the kernel of $R[T] \to R[w]$ is a principal ideal generated by $vT-u$, which answers my question-- the details of the proof can be found in the answers that @user26857 mentioned. What about assuming that $vT-u$ is irreducible instead of prime? Now instead of $-u,v$ a regular sequence, is it a "weak" regular sequence?

Comment: The above definition of "weak regular"  is because we do not demand that $(u,v)\neq R$? (as Kaplansky noted in his exercises)? But the assumption that $(v):(u)=(v)$ is equivalent to $u+(v)$ not being a zero-divisor in $R/(v)$?

Comment: Since $\deg(vT-u)=1$, irreducible is equivalent to $u,v$ have no common factor other than units. In general, this seems to be weaker than $u,v$ regular sequence.

Comment: $x^2T-x^3 \in k[x^2,x^3][T]$ is irreducible, not prime, and the kernel is NOT a principal ideal http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319223/what-is-the-kernel-of-kx2-x3t-to-kx-defined-by-t-mapsto-x