# Concerning $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3][T]/\langle x^2T-x^3 \rangle$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals

According to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319223/what-is-the-kernel-of-kx2-x3t-to-kx-defined-by-t-mapsto-x),
we have:
$B:= \mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3][T] / \langle T^2-x^2, x^2T-x^3, x^3T-x^4 \rangle = \mathbb{C}[x]$

Consider $A:= \mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3][T]/\langle x^2T-x^3 \rangle$.

Clearly, $A \to B=\mathbb{C}[x]$ is onto.

If I am not wrong:

**(i)** $A/I=B$, where $I=\frac{\langle T^2-x^2, x^2T-x^3, x^3T-x^4 \rangle}{\langle x^2T-x^3 \rangle}$.

**(ii)** $B$ is an integral domain, so $I$ is a prime ideal.

> **Question (1)** Is it possible to somehow characterize that $A$, not with quotients?
> Is such $A$ contained in $\mathbb{C}(x)$ -- probably not?
> Is such $A$ contained in some algebraic ring extension of $\mathbb{C}[x]$?

> **Question (2)** Same question with $A:= \mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3][T]/\langle x^2T-x^3 \rangle$
> replaced by $A:= \mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3][T]/\langle T^2-x^2 \rangle$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Since $A$ has dimension one and not equal to $B$, it is not a domain, so it can not be contained in any field.

Comment: @Mohan, thank you very much for your comment. Nice idea. Could you please give an example of a (non-trivial) zero divisor in $A$?

Comment: $x^2(x^3T-x^4)=x^3(x^2T-x^3)=0$, so both $x^2, x^3T-x^4$ are zero divisors.

Comment: Thank you! Please, what about zero-divisors in the 'second' algebra $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3][T]/\langle T^2-x^2 \rangle$?

Comment: $(x^2T-x^3)(x^2T+x^3)=x^4T^2-x^6=x^4(T^2-x^2)$

Comment: Very nice, thank you! You have shown that $T^2-x^2$ is not prime in $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3][T]$, so $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3][T]/\langle T^2-x^2 \rangle$ is not a domain. (Also, $x^2T-x^3$ is not prime in $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3][T]$, so $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3][T]/\langle x^2T-x^3 \rangle$ is not a domain).

Comment: What if $A$ would have been a domain? Is there a way to characterize $A$ more specifically? I do not have a one dimensional example, but a two-dimensional one: $\mathbb{C}[y,xy][T]/\langle yT-xy \rangle$. This algebra contains $x$, so it contains $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, but I guess it is bigger than $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$? (it seems that this depends on whether $\mathbb{C}[x,xy]$ is a UFD or not).

Comment: Is it true that $\mathbb{C}[y,xy]/\langle yT-xy \rangle$ is isomorphic to $k[x,y]$?

Comment: Yes. $C[y,xy]\cong C[y,u]$, so your ring is just $C[y,u,T]/(yT-u)=C[y,T]$.

Comment: Thank you. Should this work ($A$ is isomorphic to $B$) whenever $A$ is a UFD? BTW, I am trying to ask a similar question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3810982/k-subsetneq-r-subseteq-kx-y-a-ufd-implies-that-ry-xy-a-ufd

Comment: Where: $A=D/\langle vT-u \rangle$, $D$ is an integral domain having field of fractions $Q(D)$, $u,v \in D=k$, $D[u/v]$ is isomorphic to $B$. In this situation $A$ is isomorphic to $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]\simeq\mathbb C[U,V]/\langle U^2-V^3 \rangle$ ($U$ corresponds to $x^3$ and $V$ to $x^2$) we have

$$\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3][T]/\langle T^2-x^2 \rangle\simeq\mathbb C[U,V,T]/\langle U^2-V^3,T^2-V \rangle\simeq\mathbb C[U,T]/\langle U^2-T^6\rangle.$$

Comment: Nice idea, than you very much!