# Remainder of multivariate polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

So by the division algorithm, for any ring R and R[x], and let f $\in$ R[x], g $\in$ R[x] and deg(g)=n, then f=hg+r for some r $\in$ R[x] and deg(r) < deg(g).

However, I don't know how the similar thing can work on multivariate polynomial rings. For example, in A = k[x, y], let f be an arbitrary polynomial in A, what properties should its remainder of $y-x^2$ have; what properties should its remainder of $x^2y-y^5$ have, etc.

In general, if we know a polynomial in a multivariate polynomial ring, then what can we conclude about the remainder of any polynomial in the same ring?

Thanks and I appreciate your insights.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32070/what-is-the-algorithm-for-long-division-of-polynomials-with-multiple-variables

Comment: It uses a total ordering on monomials and relies on the theory of [Gröbner bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis).